# I'm getting error expected primary-expression before '=' for my for loop

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void SieveOfEratosthenes(int num)
{
    bool pno[num + 1];
    memset(pno, true, sizeof(pno));
    for (int i = 2; i* i < = num; i++)
    {
        if (pno[i] == true)
        {
            for (int j = i * 2; j < = num; j + = i)
                pno[j] = false;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < = num; i++)
        if (pno[i])
            cout << i << " ";
}
int main()
{
    int num = 15;
    cout << "The prime numbers smaller or equal to " << num << " are: ";
    SieveOfEratosthenes(num);
    return 0;
}
```

the error is in the for loop. According to me the code is correct.

Comment: `j< = num` -> `j <= num` (in all cases). C++ ignores most whitespace, but you cannot separate symbols in an operator.

Comment: Same with `j + = i`.

Comment: solution in your loop condition ```j<=```

Comment: You should avoid using [#include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/6865932) and [using namespace std;](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/6865932)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing space before `=`.

```
for(int i=2; i*i<= num; i++) { ..
```

Comment: this worked but what the H.  spaces aren't supposed to cause such problems

Comment: This is because '<=' is an operator and you cannot add spaces between the symbols of the operator as '<' and '=' are two independent operators also exists.

Comment: Check this to learn more about c++ operators https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_operators.htm

Comment: oh, I see. I never came across such a problem before. anyway, thanks.